# if statement openerp view

Tags: xml, if-statement, odoo

What I want is to make an if statement. if it's true an image should be displayed, else the other image should be displayed. However the XML can't do the comparison because it can't find myboolean or it just can't compare the values so it's neither false or true.

Can someone explain it?

I also tried `t-if="myboolean.raw_value === true"` but it gives me the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'raw_value' of undefined

What I wanted to happen:

```
<if myboolean == true>
 <img  src="thisimage"/>
</if>
<if myboolean == false>
 <img src="otherimage"/>
</if>
```

Comment: Is it qweb xml or normal xml file?

Comment: it's a normal xml file